# Basic maths - rearranging terms

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am not a maths student, but I need to use the following equation for my project

I have an equation:

$A$ x $F(Q) = B$ x $(1-F(Q))$

Where F is some cumulative density function, x are multiply (not variables) and the rest are some constants

How can I rearrange the above equation and result as follow:

$F(Q)=B/(A+B)$

I can do something like $AF(Q)=B-BF(Q)$

divided by A for both side give:
$F(Q)=(B-BF(Q))/A$

Which is not the same as above, may I ask how can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to abbreviate $F(Q)$ as $F$.

$$AF=B\cdot(1-F)$$

Start by distributing:

$$AF=B-BF$$

Add $BF$ to both sides:

$$AF+BF=B$$

Factor:

$$F(A+B)=B$$

Finally, divide by $A+B$.

$$F=\frac{B}{A+B}$$

and we're done.

Comment: Please comment if you don't understand.

Comment: Absolutely clear, thank you!

Comment: Glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 0):

$$AF(Q)=B-BF(Q)$$
$$AF(Q)+BF(Q)=B-BF(Q)+BF(Q)$$
$$(A+B)F(Q)=B$$
$$\frac{(A+B)F(Q)}{A+B}=\frac{B}{A+B}$$
$$F(Q)=\frac{B}{A+B}$$